# Declaring a variable higher up the scope chain

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

I doubt this is possible, but I'd like to give it a shot.

I'd like write a function that introduces new variables *into the scope of its caller*.

The goal is to do something like this:

```
(function() {
    var x = {a: 5, b:6};
    console.log(typeof a, typeof b); // prints: undefined undefined
    magicImport(x);
    console.log(a, b); // prints: 5 6
})();

// Variables are not in global scope
console.log(typeof a, typeof b); // prints: undefined undefined
```

If `magicImport(x)` does something like

```
eval("var a = x.a; var b = x.b;");
```

that doesn't really help, since the scope of `a` and `b` will be limited to inside `magicImport`.

And of course

```
eval("a = x.a; b = x.b;");
```

is no good since that will modify the global object.

Is there any way to `eval` code within a higher scope?

**EDIT**: The goal, in case it isn't clear, is to create function that can import the contents of a namespace without polluting the global scope, and without necessarily having to place those imported objects into a new container object.

Comment: At first glance i don't think it is possible but i'm really curios if anyone finds a way. Seems interesting enough :).

Comment: What you wish for cannot be done, and thank god for that :)

Comment: As evil as `with` seems to be, it does the trick neatly in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, you'd need to eval, but you have to eval in the scope that they need to be define.  There is no way to postpone calling the eval.  magicImport has to build the string to be eval'd:

```
(function() {
    var x = {a: 5, b:6};
    console.log(typeof a, typeof b);  // output: undefined undefined
    eval(magicImport(x));
    console.log(a, b);                // output: 5 6
})();

// Variables are not in global scope
console.log(typeof a, typeof b);      // output: undefined undefined

function magicImport(x){
    return "var a=" + x.a + ",b=" + x.b ;
}
```

---

An alternative would be to skip the function call and use a loop.  Instead of `eval(magicImport(x));` you could replace it with:

```
for(prop in x){eval("var " + prop + "=" + x[prop]);}
```

or

```
 var str = "";
 for(prop in x){str + = "var " + prop + "=" + x[prop] + ";" ;}
 eval(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Unless you want to end up in a maintainance nightmare.

If I call a function I want to know what side effects it has, what if the the imported stuff changes? I will break everything. I can hardly imagine any need for such magic driven, unmaintainable code, if you really need to import stuff, return a object and use its properties, but don't do scoping magic, since this won't work with closures or other good features of the language.

Comment: How is this so different from `import` in Java or `using` in C# or C++? You end up with some number of classes from a namespace that you're ostensibly familiar with (since you're the one importing it) that you can access directly. No unspecified methods get executed in the process, so there won't be any side effects. You might have to be a little bit more careful about name collisions since you don't have a compiler to warn you, but that's the only downside I can see.

Comment: @kpozin The problem is there is only **one** global namespace in JavaScript, and if your script gets included on some page on the internet it will change that namespace will all other scripts on the page.

Comment: Ah, this isn't for a public JS library. This is for an internal application where we control the entire codebase. And as you can see in the example, the import method would only declare *local* variables as we would only use it wrapped within anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could just use the `with` statement:

```
function() {
    var x = {a: 5, b:6};
    console.log(typeof a, typeof b); // prints: undefined undefined
    with(x) {
        console.log(a, b); // prints: 5 6
    }
}
```

Anyway, since this will modify the such called scope chain (pushing all propertys upfront), any other call within a `with` statement will become slower. This is one reason why it's not recommendable to use it. (deprecated in <strike>ES5</strike> ES5 strict-mode anyway)

Comment: You could also directly jump out of a window, just don't do it.

Comment: I think what he wants is for "x" to be pushed into some surrounding scope, like the scope of a function that calls that little function (the one that declares and assigns "x").

Comment: @IvoWetzel: pretty qualified comment. Probably he is well aware of all the downsides and is just doing it for educational reasons? I just answered his question and don't shake my finger on people.

Comment: Should have pointed out my sarcasm their... sigh.... still even if he wants this for "educational purposes only" it should be made very clear to him that this is from the bottom up, a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I very strongly suspect that what you want to do is impossible in JavaScript.  There's not even a way to *refer* to enclosing scopes.

I'm not a programming language theorist, but I've written a lot of software. Something about this concept just screams "bad idea" to me.  Having functions introduce new symbols willy-nilly would be pretty weird, and it would make it very hard to understand a program.

It's hard to see why what you want to do is better than simply having the caller pick where to store a value. Perhaps features like multi-assignment would make you happier:

```
var x = { a: null, b: null };

// made up syntax here
<< x.a, x.b >> = magicFunction();
```

where "magicFunction" would somehow return two values. But because Javascript already has an object notation, that doesn't seem too compelling to me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much about scopes; you are trying to copy properties into variables which happen to have the same name.

Nevertheless, here's my shot at it:

```
function magicImport(o) {
    for(property in o) {
        window[property] = o[property];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the question is about scopes.  I think you misunderstood.